# How to make Stack Overflow remember page size upon log in?

Tags: support, feature-request

On Stack Overflow size there is an option at the bottom to select "Number of Questions per page". I have selected 50 questions per page. However, every day when I visit the site, I have to change the "Questions per page" setting. This simply adds "pagesize=50" to url.

I have not found an option in profile / settings by which I can make the site to remember my setting.

How can I change this in setting so that once I login my account knows how many questions I need per page?

Comment: Do you clear your cookies on exit or something?

Comment: Yes. I clear cache and cookies every now and then. I use the same browsers for web development and while developing/testing I keep clearing cache for obvious reasons.

But once I log in, shouldn't there be a feature for user specific setting? What if multiple people on same computer use stackoverflow at different times?

Comment: Those settings are saved somewhere in your browser (cookies or local storage). It would work automagically if you didn't clear that stuff all the time. Just bookmark SO with the pagesize setting in the URL.